# Capturing Video only in landscape mode in android

Tags: android, video-capture, landscape

I have a video capturing code that captures video in both potrait as well as landscape mode.I want to capture the video only in landscape mode in android.Please help me.

```
 public void startRecordingVideo() {
if (getActivity().getPackageManager().hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_CAMERA_FRONT)) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_VIDEO_CAPTURE);
    File mediaFile = new File(
            Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/myvideo.mp4");
    videoUri = Uri.fromFile(mediaFile);
    intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_VIDEO_QUALITY, 1);
    intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, videoUri);
    intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_FULL_SCREEN,true);
    startActivityForResult(intent, VIDEO_CAPTURE);
} else {
    Toast.makeText(this.getActivity(), "No camera on device", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

}